# Are fractions more computationally "expensive" than whole numbers?

Tags: arithmetic, performance

I have a problem where the values are represented to humans as [0, .5, 1, ..., 8]

But the function is massively recursive (game trees for a set of increasingly intractable problems) so I'm wondering is it more computationally efficient to use the values [0, 1, 2, ..., 16] and only divide by 2 when outputting for humans?

*(Possibly this is a non-issue with high level languages and modern processors.  The hardware we'll be running on is smartphones, but everything has to be local.)*

Comment: Floating point computations could be more expensive than integer computations.

Comment: This question seems unanswerable in its current form -- I don't know how we could answer this question without knowing what function you're trying to compute.  And $f(1)/2$ isn't necessarily the same value as $f(0.5)$, so I don't know whether your procedure will even work -- that will depend on the specific function you want to compute.

Comment: @D.W. thanks for weighing in.  I'm trying to determine how processors handle fractions.  Floating point methods seem rather costly, and I'm not quite clear on how simple real numbers are stored in a register.  The recursive functions would be game trees, but it's for a set of increasingly intractable problems and we have to rely on individual smartphones for processing, so I need to be efficient.  (Luckily, the automata don't have to be strong, just stronger than the average human player.)

Answer (score 2):

This link below compares all arithmetic operations between floating point and integer variables on various architectures and processors.

With the general conclusion drawn that additions and subtraction are roughly equal, the performance impact arises in multiplication and division operations; with integer being faster. (Except for x86-64 AVX and POWER8 AltiVec where it is faster in the former for floating point and equal in the latter.)

Integer and Floating-Point Arithmetic Speed vs Precision: http://nicolas.limare.net/pro/notes/2014/12/12_arit_speed/

Comment: Thank you so much for weighing in!  My approach has been to avoid multiplication/division wherever possible, and we'll ultimately try to use bitwise incrementation for addition/subtraction, even if it's not faster, per se, for heat considerations.  The model is compact enough to make this achievable.

Answer (score 1):

It's the wrong question.

Floating point numbers may be a bit more expensive than integer arithmetic, but this is unlikely to matter in your application. Do whatever is better for your application. Use the values that make most sense in your application.

Writing an application is difficult enough. Do whatever you can to make it as simple as possible. If you are worried about the speed (floating point vs. integer), the simpler your code is, the easier it is to make it faster - because making code faster is not a matter of floating point vs. integer, but a matter of how much time to spend on it, and the simpler the code, the more time you can spend to make it fast.

Comment: My model is so compact, even writing the kernel in high-level languages in wildly inefficient from a computational standpoint. But we don't want to have to rewrite the kernel for every chipset, so reducing operations in every way possible is critical.  Even excess heat is a potential issue, so bitwise incrementation is preferred, and multiplication/division needs to be avoided wherever possible.  That said, I appreciate the input, and the confirmation of the inefficiency of floating point vs. integers.